# how to add image from java bean to <p:tree created dynamically?

Tags: java, jsf, primefaces, jstl

to display `<p: tree` I do :

```
<p:tree id="id" value="#{beanSession.rootAlpha}" var="node" selection="#{beanSession.selectedNode}" selectionMode="single"dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

in my java bean I used :

```
 private TreeNode rootAlpha;
```

....

output result :

```
>(not image here) A
   > (image) ALLEMAGNE
      >(image) BERLIN
  >ALGERIA
> B
> C
...
```

I want to add an image (icon) on the childnode ex : `ALLEMAGNE`  and `BERLIN` but not in the parent node ex `A B C` ...

Comment: How exactly is JSTL related to this?

Comment: @BalusC I guess that the answer can come from  JSTL

Answer (score 0):

the response is to add type as this :

```
<p:tree id="id" value="#{beanSession.rootAlpha}" var="node" selection="#{beanSession.selectedNode}" selectionMode="single"dynamic="true" cache="false">
    <p:treeNode>
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="B">
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
    <p:treeNode type="C">
        <h:outputText value="#{node}" />
    </p:treeNode>
</p:tree>
```

and in the java bean, we must add this type when we construct the tree :
exmple with the seconde noode :
// 2eme noeud

```
DefaultTreeNode node2 = newDefaultTreeNode("B",                                     "ALLEGMAGNE", node1);
```